How I can send logs through syslog due to another process state?
I'm trying to set up rsyslog to process messages from the audispd program using a custom script, check.sh. The script is supposed to check if a specific process is running, and if it is, discard the message. If the process is not running, the script should forward the message to the remote server. However, my configuration doesn't seem to work as expected.
My Rsyslog version is 8.24.0-57.el7_9.1
My Rsyslog Configuration example:

module(load="omprog")

template(name="audispdTemplate" type="string" string="<%PRI%>%TIMESTAMP% %HOSTNAME% %syslogtag%%msg%\n")

# Define the ruleset for processing audispd messages
ruleset(name="CHECKME") {
    if ($programname contains "audispd") then {
        action(type="omprog"
               binary="/etc/rsyslog.d/check.sh"
               template="audispdTemplate")
        action(type="omfwd"
               Target="192.168.31.10"
               Port="514"
               Protocol="udp")
    }
}

# Use the defined ruleset for audispd messages
if $programname contains "audispd" then {
    call CHECKME
}

# Forward all other messages as usual, excluding audispd messages
*.* @192.168.31.10
# ### end of the forwarding rule ###


and my check.sh script is:
#!/bin/bash

# Read input from stdin
input=$(cat)

# Check if MY process is running
if pgrep -f MY then
    exit 0
else
    echo "$input"
fi

Additionally, can I somehow implement this scenario where logs are not sent if a certain process is running? Note that this process does not have a .PID file, so using omfile is not an option.
